# Android App demo in Website?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm creating a app landing page for my friend.. I want to show the app demo with user interactions, just like they are using it in mobile.. I'm planning to show only few interactions.. For this i can recreate the app in HTML using material framework..

So my question is how can I show that app demo with user interactions??.. It's not going to be complex demo.. Just want to show front page of app and when user clicks on the button then user will go to next screen of the app.. that's all..

How can I do that? Is there any library to do that? Or any other ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Android Studio* to record the screen of any connected device or emulator.

Follow these instructions: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video.html